# Android constant connection website

Tags: android, node.js, google-app-engine, sockets, channel-api

I'm looking for options for communication between an Android device - running a native app - and a website.

In basics, the Android device is just a sensor for movement, while the website is the receiving end and will process the sensor data. The website will then have to visualize this movement.

The goal is that this happens instantly and constantly, as the sensor data can easily reach up to 50 updates a second.

I'm looking for some proper options and possibly shared experiences for streaming this data as far as possible;

So far it has crossed my mind to;

- Use techniques like Bluetooth, Wifi Direct or USB.  Probably not
  reachable from a website.
- Use a Node.js server for a simple socket    connection.
- Use Google App Engine. The channel (java) client would be nice for
  this, but it seems that the app engine can only be the transmitting end.

Comment: Sounds like a use case for WebSockets.

Comment: @CommonsWare Could you go into a bit more detail on that? What's the difference between that and the noted option for Node.js's sockets?

Comment: I've added a bit of info about the differences to my answer

Comment: Cool, thanks. We're going to try it with Node.js after a succesful test with just simple Socket->ServerSocket from Android to Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

- Webserver: node express + socket.io
- Android device: use https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client to stream events to webserver.
- Browser: uses socket.io client to get a live stream of events.

The node socket.io server just takes the sensor data and broadcasts it.

**About socket.io:**

Socket.io uses Websockets. However, if the client doesn't support Websockets, it falls back to long polling etc... to emulate Websockets. On top of that, it gives you a pub/sub framework which Websockets doesn't provide out of the box.

The new version of socket.io (available on github) uses engine.io to provide the websocket abstraction and then puts a pub/sub framework on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

In appengine use a frontend to post data to it, no need for 2way channel. If you really want 2way use sockets.

Comment: I doubt simple HTTP Posting is fast enough for this type of application and data..